# "Unknown modifier 'g' in..." when using preg_match in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

This is the regex I'm trying to use:

```
/^(\w|\.|-)+?@(\w|-)+?\.\w{2,4}($|\.\w{2,4})$/gim
```

I found it on [this site](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), and it works great when I try it out there. But as soon as I place it in my code, I get this message:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'g' in C:\xampp\htdocs\swebook\includes\classes.php on line 22
```

Can anyone explain what's wrong, and why it's working on that website and not in my code?

Comment: FYI, your regexp is gonna validate OK these type of mails: "-.-.-.--.@--some--domain--.com" and these type of VALID mails will NOT validate: "info@subdomain.domain.com". Last but not least \w is VERY DANGEROUS cause PHP preg uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions and NOT POSIX like Javascript. If PHP runs on server that is not US/UK localized \w is gonna match also accented letters so you would match "àèìòù@domain.com" has a valid mail. Read here for more details: http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#92443

Answer (score 227):

There is no modifier `g` for [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match). Instead, you have to use the [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) function.

So instead of:

```
preg_match("/^(\w|\.|-)+?@(\w|-)+?\.\w{2,4}($|\.\w{2,4})$/gim", ....)
```

use:

```
preg_match_all("/^(\w|\.|-)+?@(\w|-)+?\.\w{2,4}($|\.\w{2,4})$/im", ....)
```