# Unknown modifier 'g' PHP regex error

Tags: php, regex

my pattern is: `/(productimages\/)(\w*)(\/v\/)(\w*)(.jpg)/g`
and data: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2ujor

and php code:

```
$regexp = ' /(productimages\/)(\w*)(\/v\/)(\w*)(.jpg)/g';
if(preg_match("$regexp", $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) { 
for($i=0;$i<14;$i++){
echo '--->'.$i.'-->'.$matches[0][$i];

}}
```

> result: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier
>   'g'

```
$regexp = ' /(productimages\/)(\w*)(\/v\/)(\w*)(.jpg)/g';
if(preg_match_all("$regexp", $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) { 
for($i=0;$i<14;$i++){
echo '--->'.$i.'-->'.$matches[0][$i];

}}
```

> result: Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown
>   modifier 'g'

this solution not worked! :|
["Unknown modifier 'g' in..." when using preg_match in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578671/unknown-modifier-g-in-when-using-preg-match-in-php)

what should i do?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you should use `\.` to match a dot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Switching to `preg_match_all` was correct, now all you need to do is remove the 'g' from your regex:

```
$regexp = '/(productimages\/)(\w*)(\/v\/)(\w*)(.jpg)/';
```

Comment: i want all matched strings! removing g returns only first matched string $matches[0][0]

Answer (score 3):

[There's no g modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Delete that g and it'll work

```
$regexp = '/(productimages\/)(\w*)(\/v\/)(\w*)(.jpg)/';
```

Comment: without G it returns onlye first matched string!<br> --->0-->productimages/Routers/v/CISCO1941.jpg--->1-->productimages/--->2-->Routers--->3-->/v/--->4-->CISCO1941--->5-->.jpg--->6-->--->7-->--->8-->--->9-->--->10-->--->11-->--->12-->--->13-->