# Troubleshooting "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash" error when changing ereg() to preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, ereg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Converting ereg expressions to preg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

```
<?php
$searchtag = "google";
$link = "http://images.google.com/images?hl=de&q=$searchtag&btnG=Bilder-Suche&gbv=1";
$code = file_get_contents($link,'r');
ereg("imgurl=http://www.[A-Za-z0-9-]*.[A-Za-z]*[^.]*.[A-Za-z]*", $code, $img);
ereg("http://(.*)", $img[0], $img_pic);
echo '<img src="'.$img_pic[0].'" width="70" height="70">'; ?>
```

And i get this error

> Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www\m\img.php on line 5
>
> Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www\m\img.php on line 6

preg_match() functions give this error

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www\m\img.php on line 6
>
> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www\m\img.php on line 7

Comment: The linked question may answer his question but how does that make the questions duplicates?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. `ereg` is deprecated. Don't use it.
2. The `preg` functions are all "Perl regular expressions" meaning you need to have some sort of beginning and end marker on your regex. Often this will be `/` or `#`, but any non alpha-numeric will do fine.

For example, these will work:

```
preg_match("/foo/u",$needle,$haystack);
preg_match("#foo#i",$needle,$haystack);
preg_match("@foo@",$needle,$haystack);
preg_match("\$foo\$w",$needle,$haystack); // bad idea because `$` means something
                                          // in regex but it is valid anyway
                                          // also, they need to be escaped since
                                          // I'm using " instead of '
```

But this will not:

```
preg_match("foo",$needle,$haystack); // no delimiter!
```

Comment: When I try preg_match("/foo/g",$needle,$haystack); It doesn't work. I got a PHP warning, Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: As per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3578703/1676444) on another question, `/g` pattern modifier will not work in PHP. You would need to use `preg_match_all` instead in your example. [List of Pattern Modifiers for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Answer (score 3):

With `preg_match()` your regex must begin and end with a delimiter such as `/` with few exceptions (for example adding "i" at the end for case-insensative).

e.g.

```
preg_match('/[regex]/i', $string)
```

Comment: "A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character." [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). But yes, you're right, the delimiters are missing.