# Strip slahes in url

Tags: php, regex, url, stripslashes

I am using regexp in php I want to use use in regexp like thatI can use it but error is popupHow can solve this problem.please guide me.suppose here $url is dinamically changed like that

```
$preg_wurl = '/^'.$url.'/i';
    $wurl = preg_grep($preg_wurl,$urls);
$spreg_wurl = stripslashes($preg_wurl);
    echo '<h1>'.$spreg_wurl.'</h1>';
```

Error:

```
Warning: preg_grep() [<a href='function.preg-grep'>function.preg-grep</a>]: Unknown modifier '/' in C:\wamp\www\PHP\get website link.php on line 33
```

Comment: Might below post will help you to find solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578671/unknown-modifier-g-in-when-using-preg-match-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can use some delimiter other than slashes to specify a regex, such as "!/!" to match any slash.  Note that I'm using ! instead of / to delimit my regex.

Comment: here is many things which are to strips like **slashes /** **dots .**
and **comloms :**

Comment: Use a character class to include or exclude entire ranges of characters, such as `/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/` to strip anything but alphanumeric or space.

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_quote() function to escape regular expression characters
try`$preg_wurl = '/^'.preg_quote($url, '/').'/i';`