# preg_replace() returns empty string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

`preg_replace()` is returning an empty string for the following line of code. The aim is to replace anything that's not a number with a hyphen. Through an online tester I believe the regex catches the right things, but for some reason this line is always returning an empty string.

`preg_last_error()` returns no error. Any suggestions?

```
$subRef = preg_replace("/[^(\d)]/g", "-", $subRef);
```

Comment: Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. It'll tell you what's wrong with your regex specifier.

Comment: What is the value of subRef?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Unknown modifier 'g' in..." when using preg\_match in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578671/unknown-modifier-g-in-when-using-preg-match-in-php)

Comment: Currently testing subRef with 9999-99.99, echoing before and after this line, so pretty sure the right value is going in.

Comment: as @mario said enable error_reporting as you will be forever having unexplained problems developing with it disabled http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: @mario - That was my problem, thank you. I presume preg_replace won't accept the g modifier as it is global by default - if you'd like to post that as a full answer, I'll happily accept!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For people finding this on Google, the issue was my `g` flag.

As I understand, PHP doesn't have a `global` flag, as the function you use decides if the regex is global or not.

Credit for this answer to [Mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345031/mario) in the comments on the question.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
preg_replace('/\D/', '-', $subRef);
```

instead. `\D` is "not-a-digit"

```
php > $foo = 'abc123def';
php > echo preg_replace('/\D/', '-', $foo);
---123---
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of the \D, and it's a much tidier way of doing what I'm doing. It was the g-modifier causing the problem though. Using this regardless however, Cheers!