# RegEx reg_match username match

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex

I have been trying to make a `reg_match` for the username to only accept `a-z`, `A-Z` ,`0-9`,`-`, and `_` unfortunately all my attempts have failed.

```
function usernameValidation($username){
    $re =  "/[\w_-]/g";
    return preg_match($re, $username);
}
$username = "skjdasASD345-_adadasda";
if(usernameValidation($username)){
    echo "success!!";
}else{
    echo "Fail!"; //it always return fail.
}
```

my code always returns fail, can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @mario The real problem here is a quirk in OP's particular platform. That question is too general.

Comment: @p.s.w.g We have hundreds of [duplicates on this](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20regex%20match%20whole%20string#q=site:stackoverflow.com+php+regex+match+whole+string). I fail to see the novelty or research here.

Comment: @mario Then it may legitimately be closed as a duplicate of one of those questions. I'm not saying it shouldn't be closed; I just feel like a question dealing with a platform-specific issue shouldn't be marked as a duplicate of a very general question which doesn't address that issue.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I see OPs main problem here in not enabling `error_reporting` after seeing the code misbehave repeatedly. That would have revealed a warning ["Unknown modifier 'g' in..." when using preg\_match in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3578671) about JS and PCRE syntax differences. But true, there are more exact references [somewhere..]

Comment: @mario You're right, that is an underlying issue as well, and I should have mentioned that in my answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `g` modifier doesn't work with [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php); that's what [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) is for. If you have enabled error reporting (see [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)) you should've seen a warning about this along the lines of:

> **Warning:** preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'g' on line #

However, if you fix that, there's still the problem that your pattern will match any string which contains a word character or hyphen anywhere. It won't care if there are other invalid characters.

Try using this pattern

```
$re = '/^[\w-]+$/';
```

This will match the start of the string, followed by one or more word characters or hyphens followed by the end of the string.

Also note that the behavior of `\w` varies by locale, meaning that what usernames are allowed depends on the server's configuration. If you really only want to match only `a-z` or `0-9`, regardless of locale, you should specify those characters explicitly:

```
$re = '/^[a-z0-9_-]+$/i';
```

The `i` flag here makes the pattern case-insensitive, meaning it will allow uppercase characters as well.