# Get part of regex based upon the given repeating text

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have regex that not getting desired results:

```
(.*)"title":"(.+?)"(.*)"stream_url":"(.+?)"(.*)*
```

How to build above values regex from:

{"id":"334",`"title":"Al Kahera Wal Nas"`,"catchup":false,"description":"","epg_channel_id":"196","genre_id":"20","pin_required":false,"trial":true,"server_id":"8","genre":"EGYPT","logo":"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/static.prod/storage/26/content/56440c5f-8504-4d85-bcf8-5984ac1f2e8b-AlKaheraWalNas.jpg",`"stream_url":"http:\/\/lv001.cdn03.greek.zaaptv.com:80\/live\/m3u8\/Alkahera.m3u8?__token__=ip=182.186.64.249~exp=1470381422~acl=\/live\/m3u8\/Alkahera.m3u8*~hmac=7d1cabf155247a1c3e3ce03d19dcdeeea484bb86f35680d9ebf27573d114dd90"`,"stream_m3u8_url":"http://lv001.cdn03.greek.zaaptv.com:80/live/m3u8/Alkahera.m3u8?**token**=ip=182.186.64.249~exp=1470381422~acl=/live/m3u8/Alkahera.m3u8*~hmac=7d1cabf155247a1c3e3ce03d19dcdeeea484bb86f35680d9ebf27573d114dd90","dvr_url":""}},{"channel":{"id":"380",`"title":"Al Kahera Wal Nas +2"`,"catchup":false,"description":"","epg_channel_id":"197","genre_id":"20","pin_required":false,"trial":true,"server_id":"8","genre":"EGYPT","logo":"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/static.prod/storage/26/content/564e6db3-10bc-43ca-8e53-2ce9ac1f2e8b-AlKaheraWalNasplus2.jpg",`"stream_url":"http:\/\/lv001.cdn03.greek.zaaptv.com:80\/live\/m3u8\/Alkahera2.m3u8?__token__=ip=182.186.64.249~exp=1470381422~acl=\/live\/m3u8\/Alkahera2.m3u8*~hmac=b4f1d4406c973e8d5806ec88da56c035d912ec370ff84d9513a7f49218eacd06"`,"stream_m3u8_url":"http://lv001.cdn03.greek.zaaptv.com:80/live/m3u8/Alkahera2.m3u8?**token**=ip=182.186.64.249~exp=1470381422~acl=/live/m3u8/Alkahera2.m3u8*~hmac=b4f1d4406c973e8d5806ec88da56c035d912ec370ff84d9513a7f49218eacd06","dvr_url":""}},

Comment: Can you post the desired string to match? Are 2 parts in **bold** what you want to catch?

Comment: I have make them coded

Comment: So you want a single regex to fetch title and stream_url parts? Is it essential to do it in a single regex? Also, I assume the part of your interest ends where the double quotes end; is this correct?

Comment: yes, I need to get single regex to match repeating text

Comment: You can't match an unknown amount of element, read this for explanation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464736/python-regular-expressions-how-to-capture-multiple-groups-from-a-wildcard-expr#464755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
"title":"([^"]+?)"(.*?)"stream_url":"([^"]+?)"
```

with global flag :

```
/"title":"([^"]+?)"(.*?)"stream_url":"([^"]+?)"/g
```

Comment: It works with first occurrence, I need for second as well as repeating text

Comment: can you  add a "g" flag ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578671/unknown-modifier-g-in-when-using-preg-match-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

`"title":"([^"]+?)"(.*?)|"stream_url":"([^"]+?)"`

It is based upon the answer from baddger964 but modified to put `|` so that it will match each instance separately