# Image URL preg_match failing, can't figure out why

Tags: php, regex

So I tested this pattern at regex101, and it works, but when I load it up into PHP I keep getting false, can someone please explain to me why?

`preg_match('/^(https?|ftp):\/\/.*(jpeg|png|gif|bmp|jpg)/gi', $_POST['damageImage'])`

the `$_POST` would be equal to `http://domain.com/hello/random-230x190.png` for example sake.

I have also tried this with `preg_match_all()` still recieving a false. All I want to do is a simple if-else statement and I can't get past this simple thing. Its got me stumped, what is the overall pitfall I am tripping over here?

Comment: Remove `g` modifier. `'/^(https?|ftp):\/\/.*(jpeg|png|gif|bmp|jpg)/i'`. You might also want to anchor it at the end with `$`: `'/^(https?|ftp):\/\/.*(jpeg|png|gif|bmp|jpg)$/i'`

Comment: Yea, that was it.. I actually tried a varient without it earlier and must have still had something off, and for whatever reason I tacked on that global check to see if that would resolve it at one point. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unknown modifier 'g' in..." when using preg\_match in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578671/unknown-modifier-g-in-when-using-preg-match-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove g modifier

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/hello/random-230x190.png';
preg_match('/^(https?|ftp):\/\/.*(jpeg|png|gif|bmp|jpg)/i', $url, $match);

var_dump($match);
```