# PHP preg_match exact match and get whats inside brackets

Tags: php, regex

Lets say I have the following string:

```
"**link(http://google.com)*{Google}**"
```

And I want to use preg_match to find the EXACT text `**link(http://google.com)` but the text inside the brackets changes all the time. I used to use:

```
preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $text3, $match2);
```

Which would get what is inside the brackets which is good but if I had: `*hwh(http://google.com)**` it would get whats inside of that. So how can i get whats inside the brackets if, in front of the brackets has `**link`?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand, desired output is: "http://google.com" or "**link(http://google.com)"?

Comment: From what I understood he wants the URL inside `**link(URL)`.

Comment: I want to get google.com but only if **link( comes before it and )* comes after it.

Comment: exactly what @TomaszKowalczyk said

Comment: @user7133318 can you give an example text that contains the content you're trying to extract?

Comment: I suggest adding `regex` and `pcre` tags.

Comment: If i could suggest non-regex solution: https://eval.in/681309...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~(?:\*\*link\(([^\)]+)\))~` will match contents in the brackets for all inputs that look like `**link(URL)` but do not contain extra `)` inside URLs. See the example on Regexr: http://regexr.com/3en33 . The whole example:

```
$text = '"**link(http://google.com)*{Google}**"
**link(arduino.cc)*{official Arduino site}';
$regex = '~(?:\*\*link\((?<url>[^)]+))~';
preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches);

var_dump($regex, $matches['url']);
```

Comment: Thanks but it said 'g' was unknown modifier so i removed it and it gave me

Comment: ////www.arduino.cc/ with all those extra slashes for whatever reason

Comment: yes code preg_match("(?<=\*\*link)\((.*)\)", $text3, $match2); and the text **link(https://www.arduino.cc/)*{official Arduino site}**

Comment: You have used regex from @Cunning's answer, please try mine :)

Comment: @user7133318 please try the example on Regexr: http://regexr.com/3en33 .

Comment: Ok I have preg_match("/(?:\*\*link\(([^\)]+)\))/g", $text3, $match2); but i still get the Unknown modifier 'g' in... error and i remove g and it gives me ////www.arduino.cc/ why the slashes i do not know.

Comment: What version of PHP do you use? `g` is pretty standard PCRE modifier...

Comment: I am using php 5.5

Comment: Oh yes, you're using `preg_match()` that returns only a single match. Remove `g` or use `preg_match_all()` and you'll be fine. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578671/unknown-modifier-g-in-when-using-preg-match-in-php

Comment: i tried using preg_match_all("/(?:\*\*link\(([^\)]+)\))/g", $text3, $match2); but it gives me same error

Comment: See my updated answer, I included whole code sample for you.

Comment: I finally go it to work so thanks. And one last thing if you happen to how can i add the following characters to this expression: '/[^A-Za-z0-9-.: ]/' I want to add these characters to this expression: ?!"','#()*&$ how can i do that do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
preg_match("/\*\*link\((\D+)\)/",$text,$match);
```

Comment: can you explain how /\{([A-Za-z]\w+)\} works because i would like to know

Comment: Sorry misunderstood you question

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookbehind operator `?<=`
`(?<=\*\*link)\((.*)\)` gives you what's inside braces if the text behind is `**link`

**Update**:

Here's a [PHP example](https://3v4l.org/e6P32)

Here's a [regex example](https://regex101.com/r/wSQ65l/1)

Comment: it says Unknown modifier '\'

Comment: If you are yousing double quotes for string literal, use `\\` instead of `\`. In double quotes `\` is the escape character.

Comment: i misunderstand, this is what i have what is wrong with it, preg_match("(?<=\*\*link)\((.*)\)", $text3, $match2);

Comment: I have updated the answer to include working examples of PHP and standalone regex. see the difference in methods resulting to `$match1` and `$match2` are the string literal definition (double vs single quote).