# How do I capture all the numeric substrings from the string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, numeric, substring

My string looks like below:

```
Response: 311768560
311768562
311768564
```

I have tried:

```
$success_pattern="Response: ((\d+)[\n])*"; 
$response="Response: 311768560\n311768562\n311768564\n311768566";
preg_match("/$success_pattern/i", $response, $match);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Response: 311768560 311768562 311768564
    [1] => 311768564
    [2] => 311768564
)
```

I need an array containing all the numbers as output like:

```
array('311768560','311768562','311768564');
```

Comment: as you want by only preg_match then let me know, is it fixed that there will be 3 numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string="Response: 311768560 311768562 311768564";
preg_match_all("/[\d]+/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 311768560
            [1] => 311768562
            [2] => 311768564
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but i want use only preg_match not preg_match_all

Comment: @mateors For finding multiple matches you have to go for `preg_match_all`

Comment: i refer to this site https://regex101.com/ they said A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data, so i guess there should be a solution, are you sure preg_match_all is the only solution? thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578671/unknown-modifier-g-in-when-using-preg-match-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Try not to get too hung up on a specific function like `preg_match()`. PHP offers several ways to generate your desired output.  I'll show you three different approaches:

**Input**:

```
$response = "Response: 311768560
311768562
311768564";
```

**Method #1**: `explode()` with `substr()` and `strpos()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VcYNg))

```
$array = explode("\r\n", substr($response, strpos($response, ' ') + 1));
```

*note, this method assumes that the first string (`Response` ) is the only unwanted substring and that it is always first.  Also, the `\r` may not be necessary depending on your coding environment.  This is probably the fastest of my list of methods because it doesn't use regex, but it does require 3 function calls and one incrementation -- not to mention it may be too literal for your actual use case.

**Method #2**: `preg_match_all()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/heDnY))

```
$array = preg_match_all('/\d+/', $response, $out) ? $out[0] : [];
```

This method is very direct, fast, and requires minimal code.  If there are any drawbacks at all, they are that the `preg_match_all()` returns a true|false result and generates an output variable in the form of a multidimensional array.  To modify this output to suit your one-dimensional requirement, I place an inline condition at the end of the function which delivers the desired data to `$array`.

**Method #3**: `preg_split()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nDRkP))

```
$array = preg_split('/\D+/', $response, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

This function behaves just like `explode()` except it wields the power of regex.  The pattern identifies all non-digital substrings and uses them as "delimiters" and splits the string on each of them.  For your input, the first delimiter is "Response: ", then the newline character(s) after: "311768560" and "311768562". The beauty of `preg_split()` is that it directly provides the one-dimensional array that you are seeking.

**Output**:

No matter which of the above methods you try, you will receive the same correct output: `$array = array('311768560', '311768562', '311768564');`

If any of these methods fail your actual use case, then it is probably the product of your `$response` string being too different from the sample data that you have posted here.

Answer (score -1):

Use Array_shift() function

```
<?php
$str = "Response: 311768560 311768562 311768564";
$s = explode(" ",$str);
$p = array_shift($s);
print_r($s);
?>
```

output

```
Array (
    [0] => 311768560
    [1] => 311768562
    [2] => 311768564 )
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need only using preg_match

Comment: You have changed the input to suit your method.  `$str` does not accurately represent the OP's sample input.